# Why is the Riemannian Curvature tensor considered a $(3,1)$ type tensor?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, tensors

Why is the Riemannian Curvature tensor considered a $(3,1)$ type tensor?

Because to me, it looks like you input three vectors and get a real number... Wouldn't a $(3,1)$ tensor mean you input 3 vectors and a covector??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition
$$
R(X,Y)Z = \nabla_X \nabla_Y Z - \nabla_Y \nabla_X Z - \nabla_{[X,Y]} Z
$$
which is a vector. Thus, $R$ takes in $3$ vectors and outputs a vector.

Comment: Ugh lol obviously thanks man.... don’t know what I was thinking

Comment: I've actually confused myself on this exact thing before. I think the trouble is that there's many ways to think about tensors of type $(r,s)$ because of the isomorphism $V \cong V^{**}$. Usually it's best to think of it as an object that eats $r$ vectors and $s$ covectors. But, in this case, I think it's more natural to think about it as something that eats $r$ vectors and $s-1$ covectors and spits out a vector.

Comment: check here below and you might enlighten your thoughts

Answer (score 0):

On an holonomic basis you have 
$$R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k=R^s{}_{ijk}\partial_s.$$
So pairing as
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle dx^t,R(\partial_i,\partial_j)\partial_k\rangle&=&\langle dx^t,R^s{}_{ijk}\partial_s\rangle\\
&=&R^s{}_{ijk}\delta^t{}_s\\
&=&R^t{}_{ijk}
\end{eqnarray*}
you get your result.